# Stop ImageMagick from pre-multiplying during composite

Tags: imagemagick

ImageMagick is premultiplying transparent pixels. This causes a gray outline to appear during subsequent transformations.

For example:

```
$ convert -size 1085x558 xc:"rgba(0,0,0,0)" PNG32:temp.png
$ composite -gravity center samples/logo_white.png temp.png PNG32:temp.png
```

Here are the [source](http://f.cl.ly/items/2d3l190F0D1L192u3k09/logo_white.png) and [resulting](http://f.cl.ly/items/2P0t2c1W3n1s093V1C3K/temp.png) images.

[Here](http://screencast.com/t/h04mFgXKMpHo) is a video showing that the temp.png image has had its transparent pixels turned from white to black.

Is there a way to force ImageMagick to leave fully transparent pixels alone rather than changing them to black?